# Error when loading a Kali Linux image into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

When starting the VirtualBox loaded with Kali Linux, I get the below dialog box:

[image]

When I go into Settings to investigate the error, a warning message says to disable hardware virtualisation as below:

[image]

What should I try next ?
Are these errors related to one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most default Linux and Windows operating systems are now 64-bit.

You need to enable the BIOS settings to allow this.

Start your host computer in BIOS.

In the BIOS settings, normally power, make sure VT-x is enabled (default is not-enabled). If there is a setting for Hardware Virtualization, enable that as well.

Restart your computer and then start your Kali system. It should start fine.

Posted from Kali 2021.1 64-bit.